# Infinitely many squares in any AP with integer $a, d$.

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

Following from questions [2090325](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090325/if-there-is-one-perfect-square-in-an-arithmetic-progression-then-there-are-infi) and [2090607](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090607/n-th-power-in-an-ap), is it possible to show that any AP with first term $a$ and common difference $d$, where $a,d\in\mathbb N$ must contain a square and, following from question [2090325](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090325/if-there-is-one-perfect-square-in-an-arithmetic-progression-then-there-are-infi), infinitely many squares? If not, then what conditions can be placed on $a$ or $d$ such that this is true?

As a partial answer to the last part, 
from question [2090325](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090325/if-there-is-one-perfect-square-in-an-arithmetic-progression-then-there-are-infi), we can specify that if $a$ is a perfect square then there are infinitely many perfect squares  in the AP.

**Addendum**

Following from comments by @lulu below, here's [the Wikipedia entry for Quadratic Residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue).

Comment: This is clearly false.  Take $a=3$ and $d=9$.  Every term is divisible by $3$ but not by $9$.

Comment: As a different sort of counterexample, let $a = 2$ and $d=5$.  Note that $2+5k$ can never be a square as $2$ is not a square $\pmod 5$.

Comment: @lulu - thanks, good counterexamples.  Any thoughts on the second part?

Comment: My second counterexample is the general answer.  That is, there is some (hence infinitely many) squares in the progression iff $a$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod d$.  That's more or less the definition of a quadratic residue.

Comment: @lulu - ok so that means that the only condition for the AP to have a square (and infinitely many squares) is that $a$ must be  $0,1 \mod d$?

Comment: Of course not.  $2$ is a square $\pmod 7$, say.  Indeed $2+7\times 1=9$, a square. For $d=p$ a prime there are $\frac {p-1}2$ squares $\pmod p$.

Comment: @lulu - Great. Would you care to combine your comments into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an obstruction $\pmod d$.  Specifically, the goal is equivalent to the statement "$a$ is a square $\pmod d$".  Indeed,  $$a+dk=x^2\implies x^2\equiv a \pmod d$$  Conversely, solving $x^2\equiv a \pmod d$ means there is some integer $k$ with $a+dk=x^2$.

Thus, for example, you can not have a square in the progression $\{3,8,13,18,\cdots\}$ because $3$ is not a square $\pmod 5$.